# Need help with a tricky inequality problem

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, machine-learning

I need help with this inequality:

Given that $y \geq 1$ and $x > 0$ and knowing that $y \geq 4 x \ln(x)$ show that this implies $y \geq x \ln(2y)$.


I saw this problem while reading a theoretical machine learning paper and it says this inequality follows but I have attempted many things including going directly from the assumption to working backwards. Seeing on desmos the inequality does seem to hold for the values of x,y listed. Also it may be important to note that y is a sample size (so natural numbers). Thank you!

Comment: The first inequality is equivalent to $x\le W\left(\frac{y}{4}\right)$ and the second with $x\le \frac{y}{\ln(2y)}$ so what you need to prove is that $W\left(\frac{y}{4}\right)\le \frac{y}{\ln(2y)}$ for $y\le 1$, where $W$ is the Lambert function. BTW, could you please reference the paper?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately for privacy reasons at this stage I cannot reference the paper, sorry.

Comment: ... I wanted to say "for $y\ge 1$" in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that $y \ge 1$, $x \gt 0$ and

$$y \ge 4x\ln(x) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Then it's asked to show this implies

$$y \ge x\ln(2y) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This can be done by splitting the range of $x$ into $2$ cases:

**Case $1$: $x \le 1$**

We have $\ln(x) \le 0 \implies 4x\ln(x) \le 0$, so \eqref{eq1A} is true since $y \ge 1$. Next, set

$$f(y) = y - \ln(2y) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This gives $f(1) = 1 - \ln(2) \approx 0.307 \gt 0$. Also, since $y \ge 1$, then

$$f'(y) = 1 - \frac{1}{y} \ge 0 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This shows $f(y)$ is an increasing function, and thus always positive, so

$$y - \ln(2y) \gt 0 \implies y \gt \ln(2y) \ge x\ln(2y) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

which proves that \eqref{eq2A} holds.

**Case $2$: $x \gt 1$**

Define

$$g(x) = y - x\ln(2y) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since $y \ge 1 \implies \ln(2y) \gt 0$, then for $x \gt 0$, note $g(x)$ is a strictly decreasing function in $x$, with it reaching $0$ at

$$x_1 = \frac{y}{\ln(2y)} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

so for any $x \lt x_1$ we have $g(x) \gt 0$. Next, define

$$h(y; x) = y - 4x\ln(x) \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Since both $4x$ and $\ln(x)$ are positive and strictly increasing functions, then $4x\ln(x)$ is strictly increasing in $x$, so $-4x\ln(x)$ is strictly decreasing. Thus, if $h(y; x_1) \lt 0$, then there's an $x_2 \lt x_1$ such that $h(y; x_2) = 0$. As such, only $x \le x_2$ satisfies \eqref{eq1A}, with these $x$ also satisfying \eqref{eq2A}. To show this, first note

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h(y; x_1) & = y - \frac{4y\ln\left(\frac{y}{\ln(2y)}\right)}{\ln(2y)} \\
& = y\left(1 - 4\left(\frac{\ln(y) - \ln(\ln(2y))}{\ln(2y)}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Next, since $y \ge 1$, then the sign of $h(y; x_1)$ is the same as that of

$$h_1(y) = 1 - 4\left(\frac{\ln(y) - \ln(\ln(2y))}{\ln(2y)}\right)  \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Using the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) and [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) when differentiating gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h'_1(y) & = -4\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{\ln(2y)}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right)\ln(2y) - \left(\ln(y) - \ln(\ln(2y)\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)}{(\ln(2y))^2}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{-4}{y(\ln(2y))^2}\right)\left(\ln(2y) - 1 - \ln(y) + \ln(\ln(2y))\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{-4}{y(\ln(2y))^2}\right)\left(\ln(2) - 1 + \ln(\ln(2y))\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

This gives

$$h'_2(y_1) = 0 \implies \ln(\ln(2y_1)) = 1 - \ln(2) \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

Note $y_1 \approx 1.946$, with $h'_1(y) \gt 0$ for $y \lt y_1$ and $h'_1(y) \lt 0$ for $y \gt y_1$. Thus, $h_1(y_1) \approx -0.05704$ is a maximum (with the corresponding $h(y_1; x_1) \approx -0.111$). Since this is $\lt 0$, then as discussed previously, this means that if \eqref{eq1A} holds, then so does \eqref{eq2A} in this case as well.

Comment: Wonderfully written, was extremely helpful!

Comment: I have two questions, one I believe in the last paragraph you meant to write "... and $h_1' (y) < 0 $ for $y>y_1$" instead of $y>y_0$. I also wanted to ask for future work how did you come up with an elegant proof of defining h(y;x) and then using a choice of x and its monotonicity to show the result is true. Is there a formula or rulebook on proving inequalities you can point me to? Thanks again!

Comment: @QuantumPanda You're welcome. Also, thank you for pointing out my typo when I changed $y_0$ to $y_1$ & forgot to also change it there. I've now corrected this. As for how I came up with my elegant proof, I don't know of any particular formula or rulebook. I spent a fair bit of time working on solving your problem, including trying several different approaches, until I finally determined it can be solved as I did in my answer. Experience, knowledge of multiple approaches and persistence trying various techniques are the only things I know of to use to solve challenging problems like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Using elementary calculus, it is easy to see that [$f:[1,\infty)\to[0,\infty), f(t)=t\ln(t)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+t+ln%28t%29) is (strictly) increasing and 1:1 correspondence.

As $\frac{y}{4}\ge\frac{1}{4}>0$, there exists $t>1$ with $t\ln(t)=\frac{y}{4}$

Substituting $y$ for $t$ in the given inequality one gets $t\ln(t)\ge x\ln(x)$, which (under the condition $t>1$) is equivalent to $t\ge x$.

Then the inequality to be proven can be rewritten as:

$$4t\ln(t)\ge x\ln(8t\ln(t))$$

As $t\ge x>0$, it suffices to prove that $4\ln(t)\ge\ln(8t\ln(t))$, or equivalently:

$$t^3\ge8\ln(t)$$

This [last inequality](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+t%5E3-8ln%28t%29) is trivial to prove with elementary calculus. Note that in fact the strict inequality ($y>x\ln(2)$) holds.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^4>2y$ finish because $y> x ln(x^4)$, how $x^4> 2y$ then $y> x ln(x^4)>xln(2y)$.

Now just prove $x^4>2y$.

$y> 4xln(x)$ then when you calculate $x^4 > 2(4xln(x))$ you will see $x>0$ is the solution.

For x=0 this inequality don't exist

Comment: I understand that if you show $ x^4 \geq y$ youre done. But I dont see how when you calculate $x^4 > 2(4x\ln (x))$ it solves the question. Like for instance both the statement $x^4 > 2(4x\ln (x))$ and $y \geq 4x\ln (x)$ can be true but this does not necessarily imply $x^4 > 2y$ unless im wrong can you clarify please?